# If the scalar product are equal then the operators are equal.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I want to show the following:

Let H be a $\mathbb C$ -hilbert space and $S,T\in L(X)$

If $\langle Sx,x \rangle = \langle Tx,x \rangle$ for all $x\in H$, then $S=T$

Any hints for me?

Comment: Do you assume that $H$ is a complex Hilbert space? (Otherwise the claim does not hold true, as far as I know.)

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot this.

Comment: Using $\frac{1}{4}(S(x+y),(x+y))-\frac{1}{4}(S(x-y),(x-y))=(\frac{(S+S^*)}{2}x,y)$ in the real case you can conclude their self-adjoint parts are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. It suffices to show that $$\langle Tx,x  \rangle=0, \qquad x \in H,$$ implies $T=0$.
2. Conclude from $\langle T(x+y),(x+y) \rangle=0$ that $$\langle Tx,y \rangle + \langle Ty,x \rangle = 0. \tag{1}$$
3. Replace $y$ in $(1)$ by $\imath y$.
4. Combine both equations (from step 2,3) to obtain $$\langle Tx,y \rangle=0.$$
5. Conclude.

**Reference:** Walter Rudin, *Funtional Analysis*, Theorem 12.7.

Comment: I am in step 5. Let $x\in H$. Then set $y=Tx$ and step 4 yields $0=<Tx,Tx>=||Tx||^2$, hence $||Tx||=0$, hence $T=0$, because x was arbitrary. Is this correct? Another question. To show the statement in (1) is sufficient because of the equivalent equality $0=<Sx,x>-<Tx,x>=<(S-T)x,x>$?

Comment: @Duke Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Soppuse $x,y\in H$, then $x+y, x+iy\in H$. Thus since $\langle x,T(x)‎\rangle=\langle x,S(x)‎\rangle$, we have $\langle x+y,T(x+y)‎\rangle+‎\langle x+iy,T(x+iy)‎\rangle =‎ ‎\langle x+y,s(x+y)‎\rangle +‎\langle x+iy,s(x+iy)‎\rangle ‎‎$‎,

so we have $2\langle x,T(y)‎\rangle =‎ 2‎\langle x,s(y)‎\rangle$ for each $x,y\in H$. Thus $\langle x,T(y)-S(y)‎\rangle=0$  for each $x,y\in H$.  let $x=T(y)-S(y)$, then $\langle T(y)-S(y),T(y)-S(y)‎\rangle=0$, therefore $T(y)=S(y)$  for each $y\in H$, so $T=S$